# A word for something just within/under the surface

Tags: single-word-requests

Sentence in question:

> For a moment Orpheus’s mind was blank save for the vision of Cora’s crimson fingertips--rouged with _____ blood.

My goal here is to describe the phenomenon where some people's fingertips look flushed for some reason, but the original sentence is ambiguous, giving the impression that the fingertips might be blood-*stained* rather than having blood on the inside.

I want a word in the blank that makes it clear that the blood in inside the skin, if only barely.

Rephrasing is also fine, but I want to avoid using the word "blush" or "flushed" since I used these a bit earlier and have a problem with reusing the same words too many times.

Comment: oh boy, no answer in the first 2 minutes, looks like it's time for people to downvote to bump up their own questions or out of spite in being made to feel stupid. /s

Comment: I would use *flushed* here and go back to find a different word for the previous *flushed*. *For a moment Orpheus’s mind was blank, save for the vision of Cora’s fingertips flushed red with anger.*

Answer (score 1):

> I want a word in the blank that makes it clear that the blood in inside the skin, if only barely.

If just inserting a word into the blank, rather than rephrasing the sentence, there are several that can make it explicit you're talking about blood under the skin, rather than on it.

Depending on how technical you want to get (this could be a sentence in a medical or science fiction story, for instance), the following are possibilities:

- > For a moment Orpheus’s mind was blank save for the vision of Cora’s crimson fingertips—rouged with [**underlying**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/underlying) blood.
  >   [Merriam-Webster]
  >   **1 a** : lying beneath or below
  >   // the *underlying* rock is shale
- > For a moment Orpheus’s mind was blank save for the vision of Cora’s crimson fingertips—rouged with [**internal** (internally flowing)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/underlying) blood.
  >   [Merriam-Webster]
  >   **1** : existing or situated within the limits or surface of something: such as
  >   **1 a (1)** : situated near the inside of the body
- > For a moment Orpheus’s mind was blank save for the vision of Cora’s crimson fingertips—rouged with [**subcutaneous**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/underlying) blood.
  >   [Merriam-Webster]
  >   : being, living, occurring, or administered under the skin
  >   *subcutaneous* parasites
  >   *subcutaneous* tissues

Also, depending on the particular word, you could add *slightly* to further indicate how close it is to the skin.

---

In a slight modification to the surrounding sentence, you could change *with* to *from*. The use of *with* is more commonly associated with something external, rather than internal, whereas *from* more commonly indicates something that is the cause of something else.

Comment: *Subcutaneous* is fun. Adds a bit of a dissonant chord. Agree re *with* --> *from*. Could also use *by*.

Answer (score 0):

... Cora's crimson fingertips

-- her nails glowing with a blood-like red.

-- with rouged nails.

-- rouged from the inside.

To me, "the phenomenon where some people's fingertips look flushed for some reason" is not really common knowledge. I read your explanation a dozen times until I finally understood what you seek to describe in a compact adverb. Honestly, it's near impossible.

Maybe it would be useful to leave it as ambiguous i.e. whether the blood was on her fingers externally or internally. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If Cora is angry or on the verge of anger, how about **simmering**? From M-W:

> **[simmer](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/simmering)**: to stew gently below or just at the boiling point

You example:

> For a moment Orpheus’s mind was blank save for the vision of Cora’s crimson fingertips--rouged by the **simmering** of her blood.

This connects with the idiom makes **my blood boil** but without going quite so far. It's implicit that the blood in question is *under* Cora's skin rather than *on* her fingertips. Actually, the implication of the blood being **under Cora's skin** works if perturbation or anger are causing Cora's fingertips to rouge.

On the other hand, if Cora's fingertips are rouging as a result of some sort of excitement or emotional moment, perhaps **stirring** would work. From M-W:

> **[stir](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stir)**: to rouse to activity : evoke strong feelings in. e.g., music that *stirs* the emotions; to call forth (something, such as a memory): evoke, e.g., *stir* happy remembrances

Your example:

> For a moment Orpheus’s mind was blank save for the vision of Cora’s crimson fingertips--rouged by the **stirring** of her blood.

Personally, I hope this is closer to your desired context.